# Evaluating quality of swap path on Uniswap v3 in solidity

Tags: solidity, uniswap

is there a way how to evaluate whether a path 1 is better than a path 2 in Solidity?

I would like to trustlessly evaluate whether a path provided as a function argument is better than the current one saved in the contract storage.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a Quoter contract in v3-periphery which can be used exactly for this.

[Here](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/bf9fb697113476f1a45bd62f4f580a3177943155/contracts/lens/Quoter.sol#L106) is the method which returns the quoted output amount.